# Blocking default action on keypress with iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, preventdefault

This is a catch 22 I can't really figure out how to resolve.  Take this HTML5 game we host:

http://www.scirra.com/arcade/action/93/8-bits-runner - Warning has sound!

The page is hosted on `scirra.com` but the game is in an iframe on `static1.scirra.net` for security reasons.

Now if you press left and right, up or down when you are playing the game the entire window scrolls up and down, left and right.  The prevent default seems to work OK when the game isn't focused.  We want to prevent this default action when playing the game of course!  So we use the code:

```
    var ar = new Array(32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 44);
    $(document).keydown(function (e) {            
        var key = e.which;
        if ($.inArray(key, ar) > -1) {
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
```

We put this on the parent page and the iframe page.  When the iframe has focus left and right seem to be blocked, but not `up and down`.

Can anyone help us work out how to stop the page scrolling, AND still allow people to type comments in the comment box below the game?  If you block space bar it stops people being able to add spaces in their text!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I may not fully understand the problem, but it seems like you want:

1. up, down, space, etc. to go **only** to the game window only when that has focus.
2. up, down, space, etc. to go to the comment box when that has focus.
3. up, down, space, etc. to go to the main window when that has focus.

Number #2 and #3 are what happen automatically if you do nothing. So basically you want #1. I don't see why you need any code on the main window.

This works in Chrome, Opera, FF, IE9, IE8, IE7 in my tests.

### Main Window

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/Dp5vK/

HTML:

```
<iframe id="game" src="http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/dtmxy/show/"></iframe>
<textarea id="comment-box"></textarea>
```

CSS:

```
#game {
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
}

#comment-box {
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
}

body {
    height: 1000px;
    width: 1000px;
}
```

### Game Window (iframe)

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/dtmxy/

Script:

```
$( document ).bind( 'keydown', function ( event ) {

    var keys = [32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 44];

    if( keys.indexOf( event.which ) > -1 ) {

        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();

    };

} );
```

Comment: Thanks for the demo, clearly shows it working and when I implemented it I saw the simple error I had made and got it working!

Answer (score 1):

See if it helps when you change it to only catch on the game div.

```
$('div.arcade-content').on('keydown', 'div.game-wrapper', function (e) {
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Concerning the space bar issue you have to check in your keydown function if the user just focused the comment box below the game. If it is focused, then allow spacebar temporarily.

Answer (score 1):

Give your game canvas a `tabindex`. A value of 0 will put the canvas element in the regular source-based tab order. It will then be able to receive focus and act as the target of key events, meaning you can prevent default actions and event propagation for key events originating from your canavas only.

```
$canvas = $("#c2canvas");
$canvas.tabIndex = 0;

var ar = [32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 44];
$canvas.keydown(function (e) {            
    var key = e.which;
    if ($.inArray(key, ar) > -1) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer.  Implemented as suggested, the iframe html page has that code but still up/down scroll the page.  FF is ok but chrome and IE scroll up and down.  It seems impossible to catch the up down key event if it originates from that frame.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue embedding my game in iframe into a Wordpress content page. Sadly the solutions above doesn't work with `preventDefault()` and `stopPropagation()` of keydown keyCodes. So I solved it with a css class toggling to body `overflow: hidden` and set / unset the iframe focus by keydown or page scroll by mousewheel.

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  document.body.classList.add('no-scroll');
  document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].focus();
});
document.addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {
    document.body.classList.remove('no-scroll');
    if (document.activeElement) {
        document.activeElement.blur();
    }
});
```

```css
.no-scroll {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Here is the working exemplar: [Boulder Dash](https://boulder-dash.com/online-free-game/)